# xs:all following by an xs:sequence

Tags: xml, xsd

I try to have a firstname and lastname in any order.
And by extension i try to have a country, a comment and photo in order AND optional. I dont know how to do it, because Oxygen give me an error in my sequence area. Here the code.

```
<xs:complexType name="_auteur">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name= "lastname" type= "xs:string"/>  
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>  
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="ident" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="auteurSuite">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="_auteur">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="photo" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/> 
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The error is:
Cos-all-limited.1.2: An 'all' model group must appear in a particle with '{' min occurs '}' = '{' max occurs '}' = 1, and this particle must be part of a Pair that constitutes the '{' content type '}' of a complex type definition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `all` model groups can only be composed with themselves, they cannot be mixed with `sequence` or `choice`. This is specified [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#sec-cos-all-limited) and this corresponds to the error (`cos-all-limited`).

The above extension implicitly defines a `sequence` model group that concatenates the particle of the base type (`all`) and that specified in the derived type (`sequence`). This does not fulfil the constraints of XML Schema.

Common practice, if some children are optional, is to restrict their order, and use a `sequence` model group in the base type as well.

If it is important that the instance has the leeway to specify a specific order between the first and last name for each person, this can be achieved with an additional element or attribute, a boolean for example.